# Symfony. Where to place entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm developing web application using symfony 3. I'm quite new with symfony. I devided my application by bundles. But sometimes I need entities from other bundle. So my question is - should I place entities to some CommonBundle or is it ok to use entities from other bundles?

Comment: What kind of bundles do you have? If bundles are very small then it could be that it's better to make only 1 AppBundle instead like it's suggested in symfony best practices http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html#application-bundles

Comment: It would be better describe more clearly the type of the application that you have to develop instead to post a broad (and opinion based) question. I think you only need to go more deeper in the docs to understand by yourself how symfony works and consequently how to structure (and use) bundles and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is okay to import (use) an entity from another bundle. Keep in mind that this creates a one-way dependency across bundles. If in the other bundle you also import entities (or anything else) from the first bundle, you end up with two-way dependency - in this case the bundles are dependant on each other, and it's impossible to remove one, without modifying another.

I don't think common bundle will help you in this case. I myself also created like a CoreBundle on several projects, but it mostly contained interfaces or some abstractions, and it did not have any dependency on any other bundle.

Some people also suggest creating only one bundle for you app and decoupling the business code from the bundles. But if this is your first time using symfony, I would not recommend you do that.

Comment: Pretty much this. It really all depends on if the bundles that are designed have to be reusable across other applications. If they are you want to keep those bundles as dependency-free as possible. If however the bundles of OP only concern that particular application, it's ok to throw everything into a single bundle or reuse entities across bundles.

Answer (score -3):

we can make service to access entity in any bundle in the project

like :-

```
services:
    test_project.list.view:
        class: TestProject\TestBundle\Entity\ProfileSchool
        arguments: 
            - "@service_container"
```

then access the this entity like this in controller :

```
$view = $this->container->get('test_project.list.view');
```

Note :

test_project.list.view can be any name,its just demo.

Hope this will help you.

let me know if any issue.

Comment: Injecting container into entities? This is one horrible example.

Comment: have you used document yet?

Comment: you don't have to right to give negative point without knowing correct things

Comment: service can be make for thing just put path of it.

Comment: This does not address the question of where to put entities.  It is quite common to expose entity repositories as services but the notion of exposing an actual entity as a service is a bit unusual to say the least.  Perhaps you could explain a bit more as to how your approach would clarify where to place entities.  And while it is off topic, I'd be curious to see how you would use such a service.  Perhaps a link to a github repository showing your technique in action.

Comment: I have make entity product and make one function getProductId() and make one service for it. then i can access this entity anywhere in the project like this  

$this->container->get('entity.test')->getTest() 

would it possible or not?